# What is the reason for BitSet's size() method?

Tags: java, bitset

Is there a use case for the [`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size%28%29) method on the [`java.util.BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class?

I mean - the JavaDoc clearly says it's implementation dependant, it returns the size of the internal `long[]` storage in bits. From what it says, one could conclude that you won't be able to set a bit with a higher index than `size()`, but that's not true, the `BitSet` can grow automatically:

```
BitSet myBitSet = new BitSet();
System.out.println(myBitSet.size());    // prints "64"
myBitSet.set(768);
System.out.println(myBitSet.size());    // prints "832"
```

In every single encounter with `BitSet` I have had in my life, I always wanted to use [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length%28%29) since that one returns the logical size of the `BitSet`:

```
BitSet myBitSet = new BitSet();
System.out.println(myBitSet.length());    // prints "0"
myBitSet.set(768);
System.out.println(myBitSet.length());    // prints "769"
```

Even though I have been programming Java for the last 6 years, the two methods are always highly confusing for me. I often mix them up and use the wrong one incidentally, because in my head, I think of `BitSet` as a clever `Set<boolean>` where I'd use `size()`.

It's  like if `ArrayList` had `length()` returning the number of elements and `size()` returning the size of the underlying array.

Now, is there any use case for the `size()` method I am missing? Is it useful in any way? Has anyone ever used it for anything? Might it be important for some manual bit twiddling or something similar?

---

*EDIT* (after some more research)

I realized `BitSet` was introduced in Java 1.0 while the Collections framework with most of the classes we use was introduced in Java 1.2. So basically it seems to me that `size()` is kept because of legacy reasons and there's no real use for it. The new Collection classes don't have such methods, while some of the old ones ([`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#capacity%28%29), for example) do.

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4213570) contains the original rationale! **Josh Blosh** (shortened by me, the spirit of the message has been kept intact):  _"The `size` method ... was woefully underspecified. ...assuming *ANYTHING* about the returned value was ... dangerous... Value could ... differ between platforms. Repeatedly or'ing two `BitSet`s could cause the value ... to grow without bound... ...impossible to fix ..., so we added a new, precisely specified method (`length`) that returns useful information ... \[and] takes the place of the `size` method."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I realized BitSet was introduced in Java 1.0 while the Collections framework with most of the classes we use was introduced in Java 1.2.

Correct.

> So basically it seems to me that size() is kept because of legacy reasons and there's no real use for it.

Yes, pretty much.

The other "size" method is `length()` which gives you the largest index at which a bit is set.  From a logical perspective, `length()` is more useful than `size()` ... but `length()` was only introduced in Java 1.2.

The only (hypothetical) use-case I can think of where `size()` might be better than `length()` is when:

- you are trying to establish a "fence post" for an iteration of the bits in the set, and
- it is highly likely that you will stop iterating well before the end, and
- it doesn't matter is you go a little bit beyond the last bit that is set.

In that case, `size()` is arguably better than `length()` because it is a cheaper call.  (Look at the source code ...)  But that's pretty marginal.

(I guess, another use-case along similar lines is when you are creating a new `BitSet` and preallocating it based on the `size()` of an existing `BitSet`.  Again, the difference is marginal.)

But you are right about compatibility.  It is clear that they could not either get rid of `size()` or change its semantics without creating compatibility problems.  So they presumably decided to leave it alone.  (Indeed, they didn't even see the need to deprecate it.  The "harm" in having a not-particularly-useful method in the API is minimal.)

Comment: Seems like I was on the right track after all. I'll wait a little bit more if anyone comes with a revolutionary use for the method, but I guess the tick will be yours. It's a shame they didn't deprecate it. It would save me precious time when using the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

If the `size` method wasn't designed by Java creators as public, it would still undoubtedly exist as a private method/field.  So we are discussing its accessibility and maybe naming.

Java 1.0 took a lot of inspiration, not just the procedural syntax, from C/C++.  In the C++ standard library, the counterparts to `BitSet`'s `length` and `size` also exist.  They are called there `size` and `capacity`, respectively.  There is rarely any hard reason to use `capacity` in C++, and even less so in a garbage collected language such as Java, but having the method accessible is still arguably useful.  I will explain in Java terms.

Tell me, what is the maximum number of machine instructions ever needed for executing a `BitSet` operation such as `set`?  One would like to answer "just a handful", but this is only true if that particular operation does not result in reallocation of the whole underlying array.  Theoretically, the reallocations turn a constant time algorithm into a linear time one.

Does this theoretical difference have much practical impact?  Rarely.  The array usually doesn't grow too often.  However, whenever you have an algorithm operating over a gradually growing `BitSet` with an approximately known final size, you will save on reallocations if you pass the final size already to the `BitSet`'s constructor.  In some very special circumstances this may even have a noticeable effect, in most circumstances it does not hurt.

- `set` then has constant time complexity - calling it cannot ever block the application for too long.
- if just one extremely large `BitSet` instance is using up all your available memory (by design), swapping may start noticeably later dependending on how your JVM implements the growth operation (with or without an extra copy).

Now imagine that you operate on many BitSets, all of which have been allocated with a target size.  You are constructing one BitSet instance from another and you want the new one share the old one's target size as you know you will be using them side by side.  Having the `size` method public makes this easier to implement cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

It is the number of 0 and 1s which has to be a multiple of 64.  You could use the cardinality() for the number of 1s.

Comment: I know what it does. But I wonder why anyone would ever want to invoke such a method. Or include it in the API, in the first place. Am I right with my assumption about `BitSet` being an old generation of util classes? (see my edit)

Comment: It is not the 'number of 0s and 1s'. It is ["the number of bits of space actually in use by this BitSet to represent bit values"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size()).

Comment: @EJP While that might be clearer, don't see the difference.  Is there space which is not filled with 0s and 1s?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reason i think it may be useful is when we need to extend the BitSet class and override the length method. In that case, the size is useful.  below is how length returns value  with dependancy on size method.

```
protected Set bitset;
public int length() {
  int returnValue = 0;
  // Make sure set not empty
  // Get maximum value +1
  if (bitset.size() > 0) {
     Integer max = (Integer)Collections.max(bitset);
     returnValue = max.intValue()+1;
  }
  return returnValue;
 }
```