# Keeping track of leading zeros with BitSet in Java

Tags: java, bitset

So, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881563/what-is-the-reason-for-bitsets-size-method) there are two ways to look at the size of a `BitSet`.

1. `size()`, which is legacy and not really useful.  I agree with this.  The size is `64` after doing:

   > BitSet b = new BitSet(8);
2. `length()`, which returns the index of the highest set bit.  In the above example, `length()` will return `0`. This is somewhat useful, but doesn't accurately reflect the number of bits the `BitSet` is supposed to be representing in the event you have leading zeros.

The information I'm dealing with rarely(if ever) falls evenly into 8-bit bytes, and the leading `0`s are just as important to me as the `1`s.  I have some data fields that are 333 bits long, some that are 20, etc.

Is there a better way to deal with bit-level details in Java that will keep track of leading zeros?  Otherwise, I'm going to have to 'roll my own', so to speak.  To which I have a few ideas already, but I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel if possible.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The size() method appears to provide exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same issue and I didn't find a built-in solution ,But make some changes is not so expensive.

```
public class MyBitSet extends BitSet {

    int realSize;


    public MyBitSet(int realsize) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super(realsize);
        this.realSize=realsize;
    }

    public int realSize()
    {
        return this.realSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to know `realsize`?

Comment: you will set it in constructor.

Comment: My point is: the question is not to know the size, but to know the number of leading zeroes.

Comment: I thought you are speaking about zeros before the number so realsize-length will return it...

Comment: that is better if you provide an example.

Comment: @AlexS thanks.although this answer didn't satisfy OP.did you receive her/his meaning?

Comment: It's not me who need to provide an example but you.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this.  Yes, this looks like the simplest route to take.  Thank you very much!